# How do I tell Matlab that some of the data which is being imported is in Hex?

Tags: excel, matlab, structure, data-import

I am trying to import the data from an excel sheet in which there are 3 columns (Time; Id; and Data).

The first column contains time (in seconds) while the next column has numbers (Id). The third column (Data), however, has hexadecimal numbers, therefore Matlab is unable to process that information and shows 'NaN' in the command window/structure whenever I try to retrieve any information from the third column.

[image]

I want to create a structure for each Ids and display the respective information inside that Id.

Hence is there anyway to obtain the information from the third column without getting NaN error?

Here's my code:

```
[dat1, dat2, dat3] = xlsread('1');
flds=dat3(1,:);
bus=cell2struct(dat3(2:end,:),flds,2);

for k=1:length(bus)
 if bus(k).Id == 150

    i=i+1;
    can_bus(k,:)
 end
end
```

Comment: Can you show a couple of lines of sample data from your excel sheet?

Comment: Matlab will import Hex values as `string`. You need to use the function [`hex2dec`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hex2dec.html) on these strings before you can treat them as numbers.

Comment: @anasimtiaz I have added the sample data. please checkout the link. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the raw text and do the conversion yourselves:

> To get the text, you have to get other output parameters 
>   from xlsread. For example:
>
> [num,txt,raw] = xlsread('file.xls');
>
> will return the numeric values in num, the text values in  txt, and
>   the raw cell data in raw.

[Source](http://ch.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/169552)